# Cake PHP route controller/action to other controller/action

Tags: cakephp, routes

How can I make cakePHP go to ef_users/logout when I click the users/logout link?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

This doesn't seem to work

```
Router::connect('/users/:action/*', array('controller' => 'ef_users', 'action' => 'logout'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in doubt, just use as precise route as possible and put it near the top of the list

```
Router::connect('/users/logout', array('controller' => 'ef_users', 'action' => 'logout'));
```

Comment: It doen't work... This is the url http://localhost/index.php?/users/logout but when I click it it doesn't go to http://localhost/index.php?/ef_users/logout

Answer (score 2):

A couple of options:

- Make the link point to the correct place in the first place
- Use routing: http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration
- Redirect the user with `$this->redirect( url )`: http://book.cakephp.org/view/982/redirect

Comment: I cant make the link point to the correct place and I can't edit the users_controller.php. This is a third party app which I need to modify in order to use it under an intranet. So the second option is what I can use as it seems.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider using logoutRedirect which will still log the user out using the standard CakePHP logout function then redirect the user to your ef_users logout action.

$this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'ef_users', 'action' => 'logout');

More information at: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1271/logoutRedirect